# PHP array return entire section

Tags: php, api, myob

Hi I am trying to get everything in within the [] brackets. I have tried everything I could find but no luck

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "UID": "XXX-XXX",
      "Code": "USD",
      "CurrencyName": "US Dollar",
      "CurrencyRate": 0.71428000,
      "URI": "https://ar2.api.myob.com/accountright/XXX-XXX/GeneralLedger/Currency/XXX-XXX",
      "RowVersion": "-6496407278109851648"
    }
  ],
  "NextPageLink": null,
  "Count": 1
}
```

EDIT

My Code

```
   $getsbCurrencyDetailsclass = new myobsbfunctions($_SESSION['access_token'],api_key);
        $getsbCurrencyDetails = $getsbCurrencyDetailsclass->getResponsenew($cf_uri. "/GeneralLedger/Currency/?" .'$filter' ."=Code%20eq%20'{$docCurrencyType}'");

        
        $getsbCurrencyDetails = json_decode($getsbCurrencyDetails);

        $result=$getsbCurrencyDetails['Items'];
        //print("<pre>".print_r($result,true)."</pre>");
        echo $getsbCurrencyDetails
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the JSON into an array, then manipulate this array. Assuming the text is in `$json`:

```
$array=json_decode($json, true);
$result=$array['Items'];
```

**EDIT**

I forgot the second parameter to `json_decode`

Comment: I have tried this but i get this error - `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in E:\github\MYOB_API\connection.php:352 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in E:\github`

Comment: added my code in OP above

Comment: I forgot the second parameter to `json_decode` - please retry.

Comment: No error but I still have the extra info, I only need the items within the [].

Comment: `Array ( [Items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [UID] => xxx-xxx [Code] => USD [CurrencyName] => US Dollar [CurrencyRate] => 0.71428 [URI] => https://ar2.api.myob.com/accountright/xxx-xxx/GeneralLedger/Currency/xxx-xxx [RowVersion] => -6496407278109851648 ) ) [NextPageLink] => [Count] => 1 )`

Comment: You checked `$array`, but you should have checked `$result`